# Install OpenCV 2.4.9 on ARM

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, cross-compiling, beagleboneblack

What is the best way to install OpenCV on ARM?

I have a BeagleBone Black with Linux Debian and I'm trying to install OpenCV with [this](https://github.com/jayrambhia/Install-OpenCV/blob/master/Ubuntu/2.4/opencv2_4_9.sh) sh script, but it is very heavy (more than one day to run).

I cross compile OpenCV on my Ubuntu x86 using [this](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/crosscompilation/arm_crosscompile_with_cmake.html) manual, it's run ok, but now I don't know exactly what files I need to copy to my ARM for run executable C++ OpenCv files, can anyone help me?

Need I install OpenCV dependencies (like build-essential, cmake, python ...) on ARM if compile all on my Ubuntu x86 with gnueabi? I would like to know the lighter way to run a executable C++ OpenCV File on my BeagleBone Black.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Try [Buildroot](http://buildroot.uclibc.org/). It provides both BB target (kernel, rootfs) as also recent OpenCV version.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to run an OpenCV app, then you don't need development tools (build-essential, cmake, python, g++, ...).

**Short answer**: you need to **copy all OpenCV shared libraries** (.so files) to the device, and also all shared libraries OpenCV depends on.

**Long answer**: You probably don't need all OpenCV shared libraries to run your application. Once you have compiled your own OpenCV program you can use `ldd` to figure out which OpenCV shared libraries it needs, and then use `ldd` again on every single one of those to figure out its dependencies.

[This script](http://www.h3manth.com/content/copying-shared-library-dependencies) might give you some ideas on how to automate this process:

```
#!/bin/bash 
# Author : Hemanth.HM
# Email : hemanth[dot]hm[at]gmail[dot]com
# License : GNU GPLv3
#

function useage()
{
    cat << EOU
Useage: bash $0 <path to the binary> <path to copy the dependencies>
EOU
exit 1
}

#Validate the inputs
[[ $# < 2 ]] && useage

#Check if the paths are vaild
[[ ! -e $1 ]] && echo "Not a vaild input $1" && exit 1 
[[ -d $2 ]] || echo "No such directory $2 creating..."&& mkdir -p "$2"

#Get the library dependencies
echo "Collecting the shared library dependencies for $1..."
deps=$(ldd $1 | awk 'BEGIN{ORS=" "}$1\
~/^\//{print $1}$3~/^\//{print $3}'\
 | sed 's/,$/\n/')
echo "Copying the dependencies to $2"

#Copy the deps
for dep in $deps
do
    echo "Copying $dep to $2"
    cp "$dep" "$2"
done

echo "Done!"
```